# ReactJS - Adding logic before promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this function in a component:

```
this.props.firebase.getDropSites("123456").then(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

that calls this in my utilities class:

```
getDropSites(dropSiteId) {
return this.firebase
  .collection("dropSite")
  .doc(dropSiteId)
  .get()
  .then(doc => {
    return doc.data();
  })
  .catch(console.log);}
```

I would like to add functionality in my utilities class so that it validates (and maybe even manipulates) the parameter "dropSiteId" before it calls Firebase.

I imagine the solution is very easy, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I might be missing something, but why don't you just add the code that validates/manipulates `dropSiteId` before your return statement?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understood from your question, maybe it is a trivial solution as shown in the code below.

```js
getDropSites(dropSiteId) {

// you will be able to manipulate your parameter here

return this.firebase
  .collection("dropSite")
  .doc(dropSiteId)
  .get()
  .then(doc => {
    return doc.data();
  })
  .catch(console.log);
}
```

If this is not what you are looking for, do you mind giving some more details about your problem?